# Determine if a date is a "work day off"

Tags: c#, date

At my work, we are on the 9/80 plan where we get every other Friday off.  We've got a small program that shows a DevExpress.Scheduler control and I'd like to color our "Friday's off" a different color.  What I need to know is how do I know if a date is one of our Friday's off?  The Friday's off will always be every other week (in other words, we don't skip a week due to a holiday or something like that).  I have the date of our First Friday off of the year, so I think I can use that somehow...I can also get the date from the scheduler as it's drawn so I have something to compare to.

```
DateTime dtFirstFridayOff = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1);
DateTime dtCellDate = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Cell.Value);
```

Now I'm a bit lost as to how to check if dtCellDate is a Friday off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    public static bool IsDateMultipleDays(DateTime originalDate, int numberOfDays, DateTime potentialDate)
    {
        var original = originalDate.Date; // to make sure that it doesn't have a time portion
        var potential = potentialDate.Date;
        var difference = potential - original;
        return (int)difference.TotalDays % numberOfDays == 0;
    }
```

Then you'd call it like this:

```
IsDateMultipleDays(dtFirstFridayOff, 14, dtCellDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bool IsFridayOff(DateTime dt)
{
    if (dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Friday)
    {
        return false;
    }

    DateTime dtFirstFridayOff = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1);
    TimeSpan span = dtFirstFridayOff - dt.Date;

    return (int) span.TotalDays%14 == 0;
}
```